# Jquery Event Order

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function like:

```
 resetGrid.die("click").live("click", function () {
     resetForm();
 })
```

The `resetForm()` is the name of the function that is in the script that was loaded later on demand.

The data of `resetForm()` keeps on changing.

The problem is the `resetForm` does not get executed in Safari saying the object is expected

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: How are you loading the script that contains the `resetForm` function?

Comment: @sje397 It works perfectly in other browsers except safari

Comment: @Deleteman I am loading the the complete html having script using ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem must be related to the way Safari handles dinamic loading of scripts. It's probably not doing it the way you expect it to.

Try reading this article, I know it can be old, but it might give you a better idea of what's happening: http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html

As an alternative, I would suggest (although I'd consider it only if there are no alternatives) loading the javascript alone as a string and using the `eval` function. Maybe then the function will be added.

Let me know if that helps!